# Single Network Interface Deferent IP address and Gateway for Home and Office Networks

Tags: 22.04, dhcp, netplan, static-ip

I need to connect my laptop running Ubuntu Server 22.04 to my home network 192.168.0.0/24 and Office network 192.168.1.0/24 without manually changing the settings every time. Is this possible with netplan? or with the help of another script to detect connected network and select the proper netplan profile?

I have one wifi interface and cannot use DHCP.

I'm new to Ubuntu and appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm using Ubuntu Server 22.04. NetworkManager is available for the desktop version as I know.

Comment: Install it, and use nmtui to configure it?